# Call service for each row returned from other service and merge results

Tags: typescript, service

I'm trying call one service, let's say Service1, that returns a list, and then call another service, Service2, once for each row. Then I want to merge the two results.

So the first service returns a list of arrays whose fields are defined in an interface. Say:

```
interface Service1 {
   primaryKey1 : string;
   primaryKey2 : string;
   value1      : string;
}
```

Then another service with more values needs to be retrieved from a second service.

```
interface Service2 {
   value2 : string;
   value3: string;
}
```

This service can return several rows for each row returned from Service1. And they need to be merged so that the values from Service1 are merged into each row returned from Service2.

And we'll end up with a list with the following values:

```
interface result {
   primaryKey1 : string;
   primaryKey2: string;
   value1 : string;
   value2 : string;
   value3 : string;
}
```

**Adding to this complexity is the fact that all the calls to the second service needs to be called sequentially due the service only allowing one call at the time. Not concurrently as you would like.**

So my question is. How would I structure this in a nice way in TypeScript? I don't really know where to begin. I'm currently calling the services like `this.executeRequest(request_service1).then((response) => {});` and then I create a stack with the input to the next service, and execute all those. But I'm having trouble with creating the initial list and then merging all of the results to the same list. The code ends up being really poorly structured.

Edit: As requested, here's an example of the data that could be returned:

Service1 result:

```
var service1_result : Service1[] = [
   { primaryKey: "1", primaryKey2: "A", value1: "test"},
   { primaryKey: "1", primaryKey2: "B", value1: "test2"},
   { primaryKey: "2", primaryKey2: "A", value1: "test3"},
]
```

Service2 result:

```
 var service2_result : Service2[] = [
       { value2: "abc", value3: "efg"},
       { value2: "abc2", value3: "efg2"},
       { value2: "abc3", value3: "efg3"},
    ]
```

Note that Service2 will return these kind of arrays once for each row in the service1_result. And they need to be linked to the row they were called for.

**Edit:**
So the flow would look something like this:

1. Call Service1
2. For each row in Service1, use that result as input to Service2.
3. Merge the data so that each row returned from Service2 becomes a row with all values from both services.

If all of the first two rows from Service1 returned all of the rows from Service2, and the third row return only the first row from Service2, this is what the response would look like:

```
[
   {"1", "A", "Test", "abc", "efg"},
   {"1", "A", "Test", "abc2", "efg2"},
   {"1", "A", "Test", "abc3", "efg3"},
   {"1", "B", "Test2", "abc", "efg"},
   {"1", "B", "Test2", "abc2", "efg2"},
   {"1", "B", "Test2", "abc3", "efg3"},
   {"2", "A", "Test3", "abc", "efg"},
]
```

Comment: it would help if you could provide an example of return values from both service1 and service2 and desired result

Comment: okay, now we have an idea what response looks like, what is the desired result for given service responses?

Answer (score 0):

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20FromServiceOne%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20primaryKey1%20%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20primaryKey2%20%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20value1%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FromServiceTwo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20value2%20%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20value3%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20callService1()%3A%20FromServiceOne%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20callService2()%3A%20FromServiceTwo%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fromS1%20%3D%20callService1()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fromS2%20%3D%20fromS1.map(data%20%3D%3E%20callService2())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20results%20%3D%20%20fromS2.map((responses%2C%20index)%20%3D%3E%20responses.map(response%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%20...response%2C%20...fromS1%5Bindex%5D%20%7D)))%3B) Algorithm can look something like this. The result is in 2 dimensional array (service1xservice2). Firstly i am calling service 1, then map results to results returned from calling service 2. And finally i am iterating everything and mapping it to merged object. You can make it cleaner and divide mapping lambdas into separate named functions its up to you. Let me know if that's what you have been looking for or i should edit the response.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you just want to merge each item from both lists together (i.e. `zip` those arrays) something like this should do the trick

```js
interface Service1Response {
  primaryKey1: string;
  primaryKey2: string;
  value1: string;
}

interface Service2Response {
  value2: string;
  value3: string;
}

interface MergedResult extends Service1Response, Service2Response {}

async function service1Mock(): Promise<Service1Response[]> {
  return [
    { primaryKey1: "1", primaryKey2: "A", value1: "test" },
    { primaryKey1: "1", primaryKey2: "B", value1: "test2" },
    { primaryKey1: "2", primaryKey2: "A", value1: "test3" }
  ];
}

async function service2Mock(): Promise<Service2Response[]> {
  return [
    { value2: "abc", value3: "efg" },
    { value2: "abc2", value3: "efg2" },
    { value2: "abc3", value3: "efg3" }
  ];
}

async function callServices(): Promise<MergedResult[]> {
  const response1 = await service1Mock();
  const response2 = await service2Mock();
  return response1.map((item1, index) => ({ ...item1, ...response2[index] }));
}

callServices()
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I feel like it doesn't quite fit my problem, so I've added some further explanation to my question, so that what I want is more clear.